# are failed() and succeeded() exact opposites in Vertx AsyncResult?

Tags: vert.x

I m wondering, for a given AsnycResult instance, if we could replace :

`if(!res.succeeded())` with `if(res.failed())`

Because, we regularly write our functions with something like:

```
getUser(cmd, fleetId, res -> {
    if (res.succeeded()) {
    }
    else {
        handler.handle(res); // pass on the error
    }
});
```

would it be ok to do :

```
getUser(cmd, fleetId, res -> {
    if (res.failed()) {
        handler.handle(res); // pass on the error
        return;
    }
    // success, go on..
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can flip your tests this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply check for `res.failed()` which is equivalent to `!res.succeeded()` in your code.